# sql server or Tsql - Datediff and Dateadd functions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
select datediff(mm, 0, getdate())
```

This function returns the output as 1376. I dont understand on how this has been calculated

```
select dateadd(mm, datediff(mm, 0, getdate()), -1)
```

This function returns the output as "2014-08-31 00:00:00.000" which is Aug-31st. 
My understanding according to dateadd() - mm stands for month.

```
select dateadd(mm, datediff(mm, 0, getdate()), -2)
```

The output is "2014-08-30 00:00:00.000". 
Which is again confusing for me as this was supposed to negate the month by -1. But instead, it is doing it by day difference.

Comment: do `select cast(0 as datetime)`

Comment: Epoch time for sql server is 1 jan 1900

Comment: [Please stop using shorthand](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations.aspx). You are not saving any time by typing in a lazy way and you are clearly not helping make the code self-documenting. Substitute `month` for `mm` and substitute `'19000101'` for `0`, `'18991231'` for `-1`, and `'18991230'` for `-2`.

Answer (score 5):

`mm` is month, but you should use "month".  It is then obvious what you are doing.

The statement:

```
select datediff(month, 0, getdate())
```

is getting the number of months since date is 0.  SQL Server stores dates as the number of days since Jan 1, 1900.  So, this base date is 1,376 months in the past (as I write this).

When you write:

```
select dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate()), -1)
```

Then you are adding the number of months since 1900-01-01 to the date with the value `-1`.  The `-1` is interpreted as a `datetime`, which corresponds to 1899-12-31.  Hence, when you add the months you are getting the last day of the previous month.  When you change `-1` to `-2`, you get the second to last day, because you are counting from 1899-12-30.

Comment: Thanks very much Gordon. That helped me in understanding it.